# Object owned by a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm fairly new to the idea of threading, and I'm working with a `BackgroundWorker`, trying to get a progress bar to display while some work is being done. Here's the `DoWork` event for the `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    SetDateStartEndTimeForReport();

    try
    {
            PopulateGrid();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
    }
}
```

Now, inside my `SetDateStartEndTimeForReport()`, I get an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
private void SetDateStartEndTimeForReport()
{
    Logger.Info("Setting the chosen date and/or start/end times for report...");

    // Quite possibly the best yo-yo code I've ever written
    // "Look, I'm a string. Nope, I'm a DateTime. Tricked you again, I'm a string."
    var reportDate = Convert.ToDateTime(cmbDateSelecter.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // Exception occurs here

    Report.Date = reportDate;

    if (chkboxTimeFrame.IsChecked == true)
    {
        Report.StartTime = timeStart.Value.Value.ToString(reportDate + " HH:mm");
        Report.EndTime = timeEnd.Value.Value.ToString(reportDate + " HH:mm");
    }

    Logger.Info("Date and/or start/end times set");
}
```

The exception states:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

So, I did some research, and found out about `this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(()`. Now, when I wrap the `SetDateStartEndTimeForReport();` in that:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    SetDateStartEndTimeForReport();
}));
```

My `PopulateGrid()` throws the same exception. Now, I could wrap that method in the same `Dispatcher.Invoke()`, and that makes the issue go away. However, I feel as if I'm missing something a little more... elegant. At the time of the function calls, neither UI element SHOULD be in use by anything else. My question is, can I wrap two methods in the same `Dispatcher.Invoke()`? Though, I honestly feel I shouldn't be using two of those calls in the same function. Is there a better way to go about what I'm attempting to do?

Comment: The only way to modify a control from another thread is to use `Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

Comment: You cannot access the properties of controls like cmbDateSelecter in a worker thread.  Create a little helper class with the values that you need in the worker and pass that to the RunWorkerAsync(object) overload.  Cast it back from e.Argument inside your DoWork event handler.

Comment: Instead of managing your threads directly consider using the task-based asynchrony pattern (TAP). There's a short tutorial on progress reporting with TAP here: http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass data back via the [background worker's ProgressChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx). This will marshal back onto the UI thread. That documentation lets you know that you invoke this event by calling [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx)

Please note that `BackgroundWorker's` should only be doing business logic in their `DoWork`. If all you are doing is updating the UI, then you cannot do this on a background thread. If you need to retrieve data, then you can load that into memory using the background worker, and when completed, it will call the [OnRunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted.aspx) event if you have it hooked up (which will be on the UI thread)

If you want some sort of approach that does it in parts, then `Invoke` is the only other way.

Comment: It sounds like `PopulateGrid` is something that belongs in the completed event, while the other part goes in progress changed, so he'll need to leverage both events.

Comment: I just added that to my answer :)